# Rng getting randomness from operating system vs crypto rng's

Tags: rust, cryptography

this is a question that does have a lot of overlap with what might be posted on cryptography stack exchange,but it's mostly Rust-specific, and thus I posted it here.

So I have an application that needs to use a DH keypair.

It's important that this project is academic only,  this code will not be used in any prod environments.

I'm working in a context that already uses a crate called [x25519_dalek](https://docs.rs/x25519-dalek/latest/x25519_dalek/index.html) and thus it makes sense to keep using that resource for my own creation of keypairs.

The documentiation gives this example of key creation:

```
use rand_core::OsRng;
use x25519_dalek::{EphemeralSecret, PublicKey};

let alice_secret = EphemeralSecret::new(OsRng);
let alice_public = PublicKey::from(&alice_secret);
```

Which is nice and straight forward, we simply pass a rng to the ephemeral secret to get a secret key, and form there get the PK.

But this is where I start to wonder. The Osrng uses the OS to generate some randomness. But the docs for [rand_core](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand_core/) does'nt mention anything about it being a cryptographically secure CSPRG.

On the other hand, I have before used the `rand` package and it's `Stdrng` rng, to  create random lists of numbers for IV's. Since this this rng is [mentioned specifically as a crypto secure rng](https://rust-random.github.io/book/guide-rngs.html)

```
use rand::{rngs::StdRng, Rng, SeedableRng,};
use rand_core::{RngCore, OsRng, CryptoRng,};
fn main() {
  let mut rng : StdRng = StdRng::from_entropy();
  let seed = rng.gen::<[u8;32]>();
}
```

This makes me wonder whether the usage of a bare-bones rng like `OSrng` is likely safe to use for creation of keying material. Or if I should perhaps rather shoot for a rng that has is made for usage in crypto.

If it is the case that I should find another source of randomness for the creation of keying material, then I have a question about how to do this in rust (I'm quite new to rust).

It's a little unclear to me which kinds of `rngs` that I should be able to give the the constructor on `EphemeralSecret`. The signature of it looks like this:

```
pub fn new<T: RngCore + CryptoRng>(mut csprng: T) -> Self {
```

I then tried to pass in the `Stdrng` from the rand crate:

```
use rand::{rngs::StdRng, Rng, SeedableRng,};
use rand_core::{RngCore, OsRng, CryptoRng,};
fn main() {


  let secretk = EphemeralSecret::new(StdRng);
}
```

Which fails with the message `"expected value, found struct` StdRng`"` which is strange to me, because the `OsRng` is also a struct.

I also tried initializing a rng and passing it:

```
  let mut rng : StdRng = StdRng::from_entropy();
  let seed = rng.gen::<[u8;32]>();

  let secretk = EphemeralSecret::new(rng);
```

So the second question is, does anyone know if there is a way for me to create keying material in with x25519_dalek, using a crpytographically secure source of randomness in the standard rand crate?

Comment: The `OsRng` is the best source of randomness available. It's only downside is that it can be kind of slow. It definitely is cryptographically secure.

Comment: [`OsRng` doc](https://crates.io/crates/getrandom) refers to the [`getrandom` crate doc](https://crates.io/crates/getrandom), that says: "It is assumed that system always provides high-quality cryptographically secure random data..."

Comment: Concurring with Sven, on very old OS (or with most POSIX calls) it's possible for the OS RNG to be of bad quality, but OsRng is `urandom`/`getentropy`/`getrandom`, and that's necessarily a CSPRNG on all modern OS. Though if performance / throughput is a concern you may want to use that information to seed an application-side CSPRNG, in order to avoid needing 1+ syscalls every time you need random data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OsRng` should be cryptographically secure.  It implements `CryptoRng`, which is a trait only implemented for cryptographically secure PRNGs, and it's backed by the `getrandom` crate, which always uses the system's (or, in the case of WebAssembly, the environment's) CSPRNG.

It is always a sensible choice for a CSPRNG, but as mentioned in the comments, it isn't always very fast, since it involves a system call per operation, and the system's CSPRNG isn't always very fast, either.  In such a case, you can use `ThreadRng`, which will be faster and is also cryptographically secure.